# Qbittorrent as a embedded tracker

Tags: raspberry-pi, bittorrent, tracker, torrent

I have no idea what else to do.
I'm trying to create a private tracker using qBitTorrent embedded tracker, but got stuck in the middle.
I have it running in a rasberry pi 3b under raspbian. So.. I've created the .torrent file adding my no-ip ddns as tracker:
[image: torrent running with tracker working]
The thing is when I try to add the torrent on a remote location (my mobile phone, for example), and a Tcpdump the connection, I see it reaching my raspberry (192.168.1.77):
[image: Wireshark tcpdump]
But as you can see in the first image, qbittorrent on my raspberry doesn't seem to be seeding. Also, if I try on my browser to open http://192.168.1.77:9084/announce (or using ddns/public ip address) it opens nothing. I have no idea what to do anymore.

Comment: The tracker is behind a NAT. You need to ensure that the port is open and reachable from the outside. Then there may also be a problem having a peer inside the same NAT as the tracker, as the tracker might to give out the private IP instead of the public one.

Comment: hmmm I see what you say... first. yeah, the port is forwarded and reachable from outside (you see in the tcpdump the outside public IP reaching the private). But the second thing you wrote, about peer inside the same NAT.. could you tell me more about it?

Comment: I can tell for sure, that it's complicated. It helps if the NAT support 'hairpinning'. qBit probably have a setting for what IP to report to trackers, try that. Check the TCPdump for what IP+port the tracker gives out. IE what comes after `5:peers` in the reply. Also is the port really open?! Neither `http://s.tiagoaquino.com:9084/announce` or `ping s.tiagoaquino.com` works for me.

Comment: it shouldn't ping, indeed.. but it would resolve name.. you can check it on https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
I've just tried 9084 on s.tiagoaquino.com
about the 'report to tracker'.. i was looking at it.. I've tried inputing my public ip address as well

Comment: Further testing show that the port indeed is open. Trying `http://s.tiagoaquino.com:9084/announce?info_hash=01234567890123456789&peer_id=01234567890123456789&port=1234&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=0&compact=1&no_peer_id=1&event=started` gives the answer `d8:intervali1800e5:peersld2:ip17:::ffff:[redacted]4:porti1234eeee` The IP in the answer is transformed from IPv4 to IPv6. That might be a problem. The tracker also don't support `compact=1`, that shouldn't be a problem, but it might be.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that when I'm trying to download, there are two peers.. my own phone public ip, and the other peer is my router's private ip address. That's why it doens't work. I've tried a lot to overcame this by telling qBittorrent to announce my public ip address, but no luck.